# Controller with Middleware and return response in the controller not working in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am programming a Laravel 5.1 RestFUL API, but I have a very strange problem with the middleware and the controller response (is empty always).

> Routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => 'token.api'], function () {

    Route::post('game/add/{id}', 'GameController@addGameToUser');    
});
```

The middleware is defined in the kernel.php correctly:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'token.api' => \App\Http\Middleware\TokenMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

I have removed

> \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class

from the middlewares globals, because I just use AJAX API calls.
,

In my middleware, I check just I have a Token header param:

> Middleware Code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class TokenMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Token, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');


        $token = $request->header('Token');

        if($token == null)
            return response('Not valid token provider.', 401);

        else
        {
            $next($request);
        }



    }
}
```

In my controller (GameController), and in the method addGameToUser, I just return a JSON Test value, but the response is always empty (testing with postman). **If I remove the middleware from the controller, all works fine..**. I have no idea why...

> Controller Code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;



use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\UserGame;

class GameController extends Controller
{
    public function addGameToUser(Request $request, $idGame)
    {
        return response()->json(['status'=>'ok','data'=>'data_example'], 200);
    }

}
```

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not returning anything in `handle()` if `$token` isn't null. Try this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    ...

    $token = $request->header('Token');

    if($token == null) return response('Not valid token provider.', 401);

    // return the $next closure, so other Middlewares can run
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, too late for programming, I'm going to sleep :D

Comment: Just curious what exactly is ` $next($request)`?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to return the response. just add return as below.

```
return $next($request);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, too late for programming, I'm going to sleep :D

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove **VerifyCsrfToken.php** it's used for security purpose.There is some way to avoid **CSRF**.You can avoid an full route and can also can avoid specific url.For this first go to **VerifyCsrfToken.php** and edit like this

If want avoid routes try this

```
//add an array of Routes to skip CSRF check


private $openRoutes = ['free/route', 'free/too'];
```

//modify this function

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //add this condition 
foreach($this->openRoutes as $route) {

  if ($request->is($route)) {
    return $next($request);
  }
}

return parent::handle($request, $next);
}
```

Hope it will work

Comment: Better solution to avoid remove VerifyCsrfToken is using: protected $except = [
        
    'api/*'
    ];

in the class ;)